# How to make JSON data dynamic to get the value after selecting the first dropdown

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

> I am getting value from the query after selecting the option from one
>   table and it populates the data from the ajax and returning me a JSON
>   data.The problem is that I'm receiving value in JSON dynamically but I am
>   passing value only first value so .. how can I make this dynamic my
>   result what to put on value and the key to make it dynamic.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cate').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cate=$( "#cate option:selected").val();
            var url="<?php echo base_url();?>cat_cntrl/subcatselect";
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:url,
                data:{cate :cate},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.result ) {
                        $(response.result).each(function(k, v){
                            $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
                              value: v['Mobile'],
                              text: v['Mobile']
                            }));
                        })
                    }

                }
            })
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Here My controller code:

```
<?php
class Cat_cntrl extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cat_model');
        $this->load->helper('form','url');
    }

    public function index(){
        $get=$this->cat_model->fetchcatdata();
        $data['result']=$get;
        $this->load->view('cat_view',$data);
    }
    public function subcatselect(){
        $cate=$this->input->post('cate');
        $get=$this->cat_model->getsubo($cate);
        $data['result']=$get;
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>$data['result']));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you put the code for controller function? so that we can see what you are returning to the ajax call?

Comment: No need to use `preventDefault()` here, and use `var cate=this.value;` instead of `var cate=$( "#cate option:selected").val();`. I think, your problem is less clear to SO users, can you explain it in details?

Comment: Does, `$('#myselect')` is not populating on changing drop down `#cate`?

Comment: I already replace this but its not working..

Comment: explain bit more .it's really hard to understand .what your coming to say

Comment: when i am selecting mobile from the select option its populating the result but when i choose another option its not showing me on my select. but on console getting the value this beacuse of this line $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
                          value: v['Mobile'],
                          text: v['Mobile']
                        }));   so i just need to make value and text to be dynamic because here m getting only mobile value

Comment: Show us the JSON object which you are getting.

Comment: on second time you need to empty the previous option  $('#myselect').empty();  then append like this $('#myselect').append($('<option>', { value: v['Mobile'], text: v['Mobile'] }));

Comment: selecting mobile json 
{"result":[{"Mobile":"nokia"},{"Mobile":"samsung"}]}

if selecting car then json
{"result":[{"car":"bmw"},{"car":"xuv"}]}

but it showing only mobile result on the dropdown

Comment: jyothi@ you are not getting my point i am getting the correct json but i want to make mobile to dynamic if v['mobile ] not coming that time it showing blank so i want it to dynamic

Comment: use each function to access the value without it's key

Comment: can U please update the code??

Comment: if(v['Mobile']==TRUE){ value: v['Mobile'], text: v['Mobile'] } if(v['car']==TRUE){ value: v['car'], text: v['car'] can i use like that ??

Comment: you can access the value dynamically . check my below answer you will get idea @nisha

Comment: jyothi@ where is the answer for this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the `key` `dynamically` like this

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{"result":[{"car":"bmw"},{"car":"xuv"}]}');

   // console.log(json.result);

$.each(json.result,function(keys,values){
        for (var key in values) {
         console.log(values[key]);
         
         }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**ajax :** : your ajax success function should be like this

```
      .........
     if (response.result ) {
    $('#myselect').empty();
    $.each(response.result,function(keys, values){

        for (var key in values) {

         $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
              value: values[key],
              text: values[key]
         }));

         }

    })
}
 .........
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your `mySelect` drop down when you change its parent category and change use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) without using specific key like,

```
if (response.result.length) {
    $('#myselect').empty();// make it empty if new child category is found
    $(response.result).each(function(key, obj) {
      $.each(obj, function(k, v){ 
        $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
          value: v,
          text: v
        }));
      }); // end each obj
    }); // end each response.result
}
```

**Snippet,**

```js
var result = {
  "car": [{
    "car": "BMW"
  }, {
    "car": "Audi"
  }],
  "mobile": [{
    "mobile": "HTC"
  }, {
    "mobile": "Samsung"
  }]
}

function changeCat(result) {
  $('#myselect').empty(); // make it empty if new child category is found
  result.length && $(result).each(function(key, obj) {
      $.each(obj, function(k, v){
         $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
            value: v,
            text: v
         }));
      });
  });
}
$('button[data-type]').on('click', function() {
  changeCat(result[$(this).attr('data-type')]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect"></select><br/>
<button data-type="car">Select Car</button><br/>
<button data-type="mobile">Select Mobile</button><br/>
```

Comment: you are not getting my point i am getting the correct json but i want to make mobile to dynamic if v['mobile ] not coming that time it showing blank so i want it to dynamic

Comment: if(v['Mobile']==TRUE){
                          value: v['Mobile'],
                          text: v['Mobile']
                      }
                      if(v['car']==TRUE){
                          value: v['car'],
                          text: v['car']  can i use like that ??

Comment: What if you have Hundreds of Categories? If you use my answer then you are not worry about the number of categories. But the condition is you have to pass response in `category:value` format.